# How to filter in JSONb column in SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

I've the following model:

from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB

```
class User(Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    
    params = Column(JSONB)  # it contains array of objects
```

Example of User.params:

```
[{"a": "111", "b": "222"}, {"a": "333", "b": "444"}]
```

How I can filter User model to get all users with `{"a": 333}` in params?

For now I've ended up with cast to text and ilike:

```
session.query(User).filter(
    User.params.cast(Text).ilike("%333%")).all()
```

It works, but this is not the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this table:

```
test# select * from users;
 id │                        params                        
════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
  1 │ [{"a": "111", "b": "222"}, {"a": "777", "b": "444"}]
  2 │ [{"a": "111", "b": "222"}, {"a": "333", "b": "444"}]
```

Using the JSONB *contains* operator `@>`, this works (note that we enclose the value inside an array, to match the outer container):

```
test# select * from users where params @> '[{"a": "333"}]'::jsonb;
 id │                        params                        
════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
  2 │ [{"a": "111", "b": "222"}, {"a": "333", "b": "444"}]
```

The SQLAlchemy equivalent would be

```py
key = [{'a': '333'}]

with Session() as s:

    users = s.query(User).filter(User.params.contains(key))
    for user in users:
        print(User.id, user.params)
```

or in SQLA 2.0-style syntax

```py
with Session() as s:

    q = sa.select(User).where(User.params.contains(key))
    users = s.scalars(q)
    for user in users:
        print(User.id, user.params)
```

Comment: It works, thank you! I tried contains, but missed wrapping key value into [].